# Sockets client reads the same over and over

Tags: sockets

I'm doing a TCP sockets program in UNIX , but when I do the read/recv it allways returns the same data. The server send three structs and I only read the first one over and over

```
   int n_aux = 1;
   while(n_aux > 0)
   {
        struct trama mensajeaux;
        n_aux = recv(socket_cliente, &mensajeaux, sizeof(struct trama), 0);
    if(n_aux < 0)
    {
        printf("\nError al leer del buffer\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\nMensaje recibido, tipo: %d, n: %d, v: %d, c: %d, origen: %d\n",      mensajeaux.tipo, mensajeaux.x, mensajeaux.y, mensajeaux.z, mensajeaux.origen);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming you've received the entire structure in a single read. You can't assume that. Look at the count returned by read, and loop until you have what you need.

BTW Don't use structs as network protocols. Define a wire protocol in octets and write the code to send and receive it.

Comment: True enough as to avoiding error but doesn't explain why OP is getting the same struct. Usually it does return the whole data for small reads

Comment: @BugKiller If he was only receiving a prefix of the struct other than what he was printing, it would explain it perfectly actually, as well as being true.

Comment: well, SO doesn't allow me to change my vote so i upvoted your comment long ago. did someone else downvote you