# C++ Sending and Receiving TCP/IP structure

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

This is my CLIENT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct TEMPIO
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned short messageSender;
    unsigned short length;
    unsigned int secs;
    unsigned int usecs;
    unsigned short videoId;
    unsigned short outChannel;
}TEMPIO_msg;

int client();
int server();
void error();


void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(){
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    char * address;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    TEMPIO_msg message;
    struct timeval time;

    portno=2015;//TBD take portno
    address="127.0.0.1";//TBD take address

    message.id=htonl(1694367746);
    message.messageSender=htons(100);
    message.length=htons(20);
    gettimeofday(&time,NULL); 
    message.secs=htonl(time.tv_sec);
    message.usecs=htonl(time.tv_usec);
    message.videoId=htons(44);
    message.outChannel=htons(38);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0){
        error("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(0);
    }

    server = gethostbyname(address);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        error("ERROR connecting");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(true){
        if (sendto(sockfd,&message,sizeof(TEMPIO_msg),MSG_EOR,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
        }else{
            printf("CLI: sent something...\n"); 
        }
        sleep(3);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my SERVER:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct TEMPIO
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned short messageSender;
    unsigned short length;
    unsigned int secs;
    unsigned int usecs;
    unsigned short videoId;
    unsigned short outChannel;
}TEMPIO_msg;

int client();
int server();
void error();


void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(){
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    char * address;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    TEMPIO_msg message;
    struct timeval time;

    address="127.0.0.1";
    portno = 2015; // TBD

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    printf("SRV: started! \n");
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) error("ERROR on accept");
    printf("SRV: client connected! \n");

    printf("SRV: Listening... ");
    if (recvfrom(sockfd,&message,sizeof(TEMPIO_msg),MSG_PEEK,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen) > 0) 
    {
        printf("SRV catched something!\n");
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0; 

}
```

As you can see, I'm using the following functions for sending/receiving data structure:

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int socket, void *restrict buffer, size_t length,
       int flags, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
       socklen_t *restrict address_len);
ssize_t sendto(int socket, const void *message, size_t length,
       int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr,
       socklen_t dest_len);
```

My code is correctly compiled, but it is not working fine.
It is so strange because I launch the server after the client, the server seems to be stuck at this point:

```
$ ./srv SRV: started!
SRV: client connected!
```

The client is sending the packet correctly and the server is continuing its execution only after 4 sendings by the client

```
$ ./cli 
CLI: sent something...
CLI: sent something...
CLI: sent something...
CLI: sent something...
```

It is so strange, because as you can see, it seems the server is stuck between two printf (client connected and Listening):

```
./srv SRV: started! 
SRV: client connected! 
SRV: Listening...
```

Can you catch what is wrong?

Comment: Granted this will be compiler/system dependent, but it looks like `TEMPIO_msg` is probably 20 bytes. Have you done a `sizeof(TEMPIO_msg)` on both the client and server as well as looked at the relative offset address of each struct member variable? It's possible they are getting packed to different sizes, or packed with padding in different places.

Comment: [Don't use structs as network protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19778124/207421).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `recvfrom` call in the server is trying to read from `sockfd`, which is the listening socket.  You should instead be reading from `newsockfd`, which is the connected socket.

Also, you should copying the return value of `recvfrom` into a variable.  You would first check to see if it's -1, in which case you handle the error. And if not, you would then check to make sure you read the expected number of bytes.

And regarding `recvfrom`: both that and `sendto` should be replaced with `recv` and `send` respectively, since you're dealing with a TCP socket; so the endpoints are already known.

Comment: thanks for suggestion about recv and send!
And YES... the mistake was the reading from `sockfd` instead of `newsockfd` ... argh :)